# Showing the corresponding data from an intersect table of 2 other table

Tags: mysql, sql

Sorry for having difficulties in describing the context in the title.
My situation is that having 3 tables

T1

```
A|B
1|xyz
2|www
3|abc
4|ppp
5|iuy
```

T2

```
A|C 
1|1 
1|2 
2|3 
2|4 
3|5 
4|6
5|7 
5|8
```

T3

```
C| D |E
1|dfg|NULL
2|jhg|1
3|bnm|NULL
4|lpo|NULL
5|tyu|NULL
6|qrt|2
7|bet|3
8|dsf|4
```

The objective of the query is to show B with its corresponding D under the condition of t2.A should have at least 1 corresponding C value to be not NULL in its E value

I am having difficulties in showing a C with null when actually it should be included when the condition of A is matched in the whole picture by consisting another non-null C that makes A a legit result.

With the mentioned conditions, desired A should be 1, 4, 5, and would like to show its corresponding B with ALL the D of the desired A from the relationship with C in t2.

A2 and A3 are undesired as their corresponding E of C are all null and what I want to have is that at least 1 of the E contains a value.

The wanted output should be

```
 B | D
xyz|dfg
xyz|jhg
ppp|qrt
iuy|bet
iuy|dsf
```

I hope someone would understand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT B, D
FROM t2
JOIN t1 ON t1.A = t2.A
JOIN t3 ON t3.C = t2.C
WHERE t2.A IN(SELECT A
FROM t2 JOIN t3 ON t3.C = t2.C
GROUP BY A
HAVING COUNT(E) >= 1)
```

or using this as an alternative for `COUNT(E) >=1` or `COUNT(E) >0`

```
SUM(CASE WHEN registration_number IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) > 0)
```

This somehow worked for me

However, could anyone explain whether  `COUNT(E) >=1` or `COUNT(E) >0` is better for expression and which way (count vs sum boolean) would be more efficient?

Answer (score 0):

I find the question a little hard to follow, but if I understand correctly, you want some sort of `exists` clause:

```
select t2.b, t3.d
from t1 join
     t2
     on t1.a = t2.a join
     t3
     on t3.c = t2.c
where exists (select 1
              from t2 tt2 join
                   t3 tt3
                   on tt2.c = tt3.c
              where t2.a = t1.a and t3.e is not null
             );
```

Comment: This would show all the data of A which neglected the condition of t2.A should have at least 1 corresponding C value to be not NULL in its E value. Maybe I should make it more clear that A2 and A3 are undesired as their corresponding E of C are all null and what I want to have is that at least 1 of the E contains a value.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this query please:

```
select T1.B, T3.D from T1 inner join T2 on 
T1.A =T2.A 
inner join T3 on T2.C = T3.C
```

This query is according to your output shown above.
But if you would E be not NULL
you have to add to the query :

```
and T3.E is not NULL
```

Hope this can help ypu.

Comment: This would show all the data of A which neglected the condition of t2.A should have at least 1 corresponding C value to be not NULL in its E value. Maybe I should make it more clear that A2 and A3 are undesired as their corresponding E of C are all null and what I want to have is that at least 1 of the E contains a value.